# Memory card reader won't read 2GB Compact Flash memory card

Tags: memory-card, card-reader, compact-flash

I have a 2GB Compact Flash memory card that won't read in my memory card reader. The reader will read my 512MB and 32MB cards and my digital camera will read and write my 2GB card.

I bought the card reader 6 years ago. Is there a limitation on older card readers preventing them from working with 2GB cards?

I'm wondering if there is a problem with the card or if I need to get a newer card reader. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that you're hitting a limitation of the card reader.  Best bet would be to go get a new one, since you're not experiencing trouble with reads/writes on the camera.

Comment: I tried a new card read and it works fine with the memory card.